# Office.context.mailbox.item.loadCustomPropertiesAsync returning old custom properties in response on Window Outlook Native

Tags: office365, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

->Create Single Day meeting. (We save custom properties data using custom AddIn.)
->Open existing.
->Update time of meeting and save the meeting (We update custom properties using AddIn).
->Again open same meeting.
->Now run the below code to fetch Custom Properties
->Office.context.mailbox.item.loadCustomPropertiesAsync(function (asyncResCusProp) { console.log(asyncResCusProp.value);});

->Response : Old custom properties data is returned. After restarting Outlook Native, updated custom properties are returned. So, this seems cache issue.

->Expected Response : It should return updated Custom Properties data.

->Note:
Graph have updated custom properties with that event. Same is working fine in OWA (Browser), This is specific to Window Native.

->Expected Response : It should return updated Custom Properties data.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more clear on the exact lines of code that you are using here? Especially the FIRST time you save custom properties. Is that done via the Add-in or via Graph? In fact, is ANY editing of custom properties done through graph?